# No Idea to fix this Error:"UnsatisfiedLinkError: ../j3dcore-ogl.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"

Tags: java, java-3d

I just want to learn Java3D in Apache Netbeans (IDE 11.1) but when I implement the Java3d library, code a simple "Getting startet"-Project and want that to run I get the Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
C:\Windows\j3dcore-ogl.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix that.

I already googled my problem, but there where no understandable solution for me. 
My first thoughts were to reinstall Netbeans and all Java JDKs. But even after this, the Programm throws the damn "UnsatisfiedLinkError"..

```java
package javaapplication1;

import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public JavaApplication1() {
        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        group.addChild(new ColorCube(0.3));
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("sun.awt.noerasebackground", "true");
        new JavaApplication1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you install a 64 bit version of j3dcore-ogl?

Comment: Copy the DLL file to both the "System32" and  "sysWOW64" directories.

Comment: The error means that you are using a 64-bit Java virtual machine, but you are using a native library that is 32-bit. That doesn't work; you'll need to find a 64-bit version of the native library, or use a 32-bit Java VM. The "bitness" of your JVM and native library must be the same.

Comment: @joop-eggen It's not the way to go when using native libraries to run a Java program, rather use the Java library path if you really want to use this obsolete version of Java 3D.

Comment: Found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993056/no-idea-to-fix-this-errorunsatisfiedlinkerror-j3dcore-ogl-dll-cant-load ; @gouessej but indeed you are right. And nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an obsolete version of Java 3D. Java 3D >= 1.6 no longer uses j3dcore-ogl, this native library was used by the native OpenGL pipeline whereas Java 3D uses only the JOGL API. I advise you to read [the section of the JogAmp wiki about Java 3D](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Java3D). Jesper's suggestion isn't wrong, you would have a chance of making a terribly obsolete version of Java 3D work by using the 64-bit native library with a 64-bit JRE and putting it into the Java library path but a more reasonable (and easier) solution would consist in using a more recent version. I explained how to install it, just follow the link at [the bottom of this page](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Downloading_and_installing_Java3D).

Note that I'm [responsible for the engine support of the JogAmp community](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Maintainer_and_Contacts#Maintainer), I wrote most of those wiki pages and the official Java 3D user's guide.

Comment: hey, thank you for the quick reply, but i think i am too stupid to understand your instructions. 
I have downloaded the zip-files and unpacked them and i understand, what jar-files i need, but now you wrote "Now you may copy the required JARs out of each jar folder and the native library files (if you're using them) out of each lib folder." and i have absolutly no idea where to paste them..

I am very sorry but i am a real rookie and i need a more detailed instruction ;D

Comment: Have you read this? https://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/#netbeans You just have to put 4 JARs into the settings of your project so that your IDE finds them and includes them into the classpath.